# Reset Multipage Sitecore Form on click on close button

Tags: sitecore-forms

How to Reset Multipage Sitecore Form on click on close button. On last page I am showing thank you message with close button. i want to reset the form on click of close button.

Comment: Why don't you just link to te same url where the form is? If that's a multi-page form, not all of the form pages are shown at the same time

Comment: We dont want page to be reloaded. Clicking on close button will close the multipage page popup form and we want to reset it.